# Modify NAIP Images for seamless mosaic with gdal

Tags: gdal, mosaic, naip

I'm processing lots of USGS NAIP imagery which overlaps. 
if I load multiple files into a QGIS project I can clearly see the edges of each tile being that some tiles have a darker or lighter contrast than neighboring tiles.

by using GlobalMapper I'm able to put a fade around all of the edges of the tiles to basically fade them together. but I'm getting away from that method to create a full script to handle my proccess much easier. is there a way to "fade" or "blend" the edges together using gdal or maybe do some type of histogram correction?

Comment: It sounds like you are essentially trying to do mosaicing with alpha channel blending. The process for this, and a workaround for a known bug, has been [asked and answered before](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151194/can-i-preserve-a-fading-alpha-layer-when-mosaicing-images-with-gdal).

Comment: Thank I actually figured out a way to do it using gdalwarp clip and cblend since all of the tiles overlap by about 800 pixels.

Comment: Can you post your solution and accept it so the rest of us can benefit?

Comment: My solution didn't work.